# Django : generate a file then save it in a FileField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model `Contract`. When users create a new `Contract`, they only have to provide the name. Then, my code will generate a file, and save it in `contract_file` which is a `FileField`.

For this, I have a static method for generating the file, then I overwrite the `save` method of django's `Model`.

```py
class Contract(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    contract = models.FileField(upload_to = 'contrats/', blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        filename = self.generate_contract()
        f = open(filename, "r")
        self.contract.save(filename, f)
        return super(Refund, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_contract():
        filename = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'test.txt'
        f = open(filename, "w")
        f.write("content")
        f.close()
        return filename
```

Unfortunately, this results in an

> Exception Value:  maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

I suppose that when I call the FileField `save` method, it might somehow also call the Contract' save method. But I could not solve this problem. Does anyone have a method for performing this file generation then saving it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running `self.contract.save(filename, f)` add the `save` parameter through as shown below.

This will not run the `Contract` instance save method, which is causing your recursion.

```py
self.contract.save(filename, f, save=False)
```

I would also recommend using `with ...` when opening files so they don't stay open. Shown below:

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    filename = self.generate_contract()
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        self.contract.save(filename, f)
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I didn't know this `save` parameter.