# Save file (not in MEDIA_ROOT) to Django FileField from fastapi UploadFile

Tags: python, django, rest, fastapi

I need to save a fastapi `UploadFile` object directly to a Django model defined below:

```py
class MyFile(models):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files/")
```

In the API, I managed to obtain file object from the `SpooledTemporaryFile` using the `read` and `write` methods like in the block below:

```py
async def file_upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    async with aiofiles.open(f"path/{file.filename}", "wb") as media:
        cont = await file.read()
        await media.write(cont)
```

Then I try to convert the new file to `FieldFile` type in Django to be able to save it in  the `MyFile.file` field but it kept returning a `TypeError` with the description: write() argument must be str, not generator

```py
from django.core.files import File as DjangoFile


async def file_upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    ...

    async with aiofiles.open(f"path/{file.filename}") as media:
        d_file = DjangoFile(media)

        file_model = MyFile()
        file_model.file.save(file.filename, d_file)
        file_model.save()

    return {"ok": True}
```

The stack trace revealed `file_model.file.save(file.filename, d_file)` as the offending line.

```bash
>>> type(file.filename)
str

>>> type(d_file)
<class 'django.core.files.base.File'>
```

Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

So from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68758613/django-generate-a-file-then-save-it-in-a-filefield) I decided to save `MyFile` through model method which essentially checks for latest file in `dir` and saves that in the `file` field when it gets called from within the `upload_file` api code as shown:

```py
async def file_upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    async with aiofiles.open(f"path/{file.filename}", "wb") as media:
        cont = await file.read()
        await media.write(cont)
    
    # usage: implemented in MyFile.save
    d_file = MyFile()
    await d_file.asave()
```

Then in the model I refactored the save() method like so:

```
class MyFile(models):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files/")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        filename = self.generate_file()

        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            self.file.save(filename, f, save=False)  # False to avoid recurssion error
        return super(File, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    async def asave(
        self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None
    ):
        return await sync_to_async(self.save)(
            force_insert=force_insert,
            force_update=force_update,
            using=using,
            update_fields=update_fields,
        )

    @staticmethod
    def generate_file():
        import glob
        import os

        files = glob.glob("path/*")  # * means all, if specific format needed then *.csv
        latest = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
        return latest
```